# How to stop JS loop at penultimate record? (xml data)

Tags: javascript, xml, loops

I have the following code to loop through a small number of XML records, I would like it to perform the below but on the last record not include the pipe at the end.

I'm an enthusiastic novice so all comments are welcome. Thank you.

```
xmlMan=loadXMLDoc("myxmlurl.xml");
y=xmlMan.getElementsByTagName("manager");

for(j=0;j<y.length;j++)
{
groupname=y[j].getAttribute("name");
flair=y[j].getAttribute("flair");
color=y[j].getAttribute("colour");

document.write("<a href=\"#" + groupname + "\">" + flair + "<\/a> |");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the closing "a" tag with this:

```
"<\/a>" + ((j == y.length-1) ? "" : " |"));
```

That's a conditional operator, which is a ternary operator (if else)

Comment: This is great, thank you. And as a bonus, I understand it too! I thought it may have been something to do with y-1 but I had no idea where to put it.